# Magento CCAvenue Payment Integration

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, ccavenue

How might I integrate CCavenue in Magento?

Comment: CC Avenue has updated their payment gateway to a new "multi currency" or MCPG payment gateway. You can check this extension out for that: http://gremlin.io/shop/magento-extensions/cc-avenue-multi-currency-payment-gateway-mcpg-magento

Answer (score 5):

Hi hiren...

CCAVENUE team in india provides a magento module. Call them up and they email it to you for free. It works with Magento CE 1.6.2.

I have recently implemented it on my website.

It has a small bug with variable not defined which is easily sorted..

The process of integration is as follows:

Step1: Get module from CCAVENUE

Step2: Get your working key from CCAVENUE site. Keep your merchant id handy.

Step3: Open the module folder. Copy the folder Avenues to magento\app\code\core\Mage

Step4: From Module folder Copy the file Mage_Avenues .xml to magento\app\etc\modules

Step5: From module folder Copy the folder avenues to magento app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template

Step6: Open ..\app\code\core\Mage\avenues\controllers\StandardController.php and mention your working key in it.

Step7: Open ..\app\code\core\Mage\avenues\controllers\libfuncs.php goto line 56. function cdec, and add $dec = 0; within it before the loop. (this solves the variable not defined bug)

Step8: In Magento backend Refresh all cache and reindex all

Step9: In CCAVENUE backend setup redirect page.

Step10: SETTING IT UP IN MAGENTO: •  Click on configuration, Click on payment methods, Select Cavenuepayment, Enter the merchant_Id, Enter the workingkey Save configuration

Now, this should successfully redirect you to success page wherein you can show order number etc. Login into the Magento backend and it will show the order details.

V IMP: In magento backend it will show REDIRECTED TO CCAVENUE and payment as pending/due. This will automatically change to payment received when you raise the invoice through Magento. This is how it works in MAgento. What is important is to log into your CCAVENUe account and check whether payment has been received there or not. Payment should show there. (orders usually take around 30 minutes to show up in CCAVENUE)

Hope this helps...

It helps to set permissions favourably. Allow read/write access to folders. Ive seen it also helps to HIDE php warnings for this module to work effectively.

Comment: hey hiren... if you want i can send you the module made by the CCAVENUE... just let me know...

Comment: Hi moody.. I am developing magento site with ccavenue payment gateway. I tried contacting ccavenue guys but they are not responding for more than 2 days.. Can you pls send me that module??

Comment: hi Moody.. Can you please send me the CCAvenue module for Magento? Please give me your skype id.

Comment: " raise the invoice through Magento." HOW ?

Answer (score 2):

If you request to CCAvenue Payment Gateway integration team, they will give you a Magento module that will be ready to use. Hope you can get that module & get that running in your Magento website.

Comment: No, They dont have module for Magento

Answer (score 2):

They do have a module for it, which I got from them and it installed successfully. Only issue is that there is no confirmation if the payment made or not. This is how it works:

ON checkout page there comes the CCAvenue option.
I checked it and clicked on place order.
it redirects to the ccavenue payment page.
I made the payment, it redirected back to my site sucessfully.

but in admin order details it just says that redirected to CCAvenue, No confirmation if payment was successful or not.